# Parsing techniques for runtime language alteration

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, raku, dynamic-languages

Looking at Rakudo Perl6 I wonder if there are techniques for parsing and lexical analyses that allow to alter/extend the syntax of the language and that are efficient and not to hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

"No". [*edit: as of the time of the question*]  If the question is about lexing/parsing Perl, its pretty hard.  We (see my bio for "we") have a Perl5 lexer.  We have really good lexer-generator tools (Unicode, multi-state, regexps complete with "not *regexp*" built-in).  The Perl lexer was a royal headache to build; we ended up with something like 50 lexical modes (each with its own set of token definitions) to handle the lexing part.

We're staring at the parsing part and today we are lucky and don't have a direct need to do it, so we've avoided this so far.  Apparantly the language is ambiguous depending on the dynamic definitions of various identifiers, so how you interpret (parse) a phrase at one moment isn't statically decidable.  We think we can do it using a GLR parser that handles ambiguities and just simply hold on to the ambiguities as possible runtime alternatives.  I'll let you know in several months.

Comment: This answer is about Perl 5. The question was about Perl 6. The answer for the latter is an emphatic YES. To see just how deep this goes check out this recent blog post discussing bending P6 syntax so far that [you could trivially embed SQL inside P6 inside HTML inside P6](http://strangelyconsistent.org/blog/macros-define-your-own-literals-day).

Comment: @raiph: Yes, you are right. At the time this was written, Perl6 seemed a lot more nebulous, so the answer was written from an "outside Perl6" perspective.  I suggest you add your comment as an answer.  [This goes to prove that answers on SO are not permanent; they get stale].

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PEGs. There are languages that are based on PEGs ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar ), which are extendable, for example:

http://www.chrisseaton.com/katahdin/

http://www.meta-alternative.net/mbase.html

Perl5 and Perl6 grammars could be easily defined in PEG form (and I might be wrong, but the current Perl6 is most likely implemented this way).